# How to mirror two displays with different aspect ratios

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have two monitors: an ultrawide with resolution 3440x1440 and a TV with resolution 3840x2140. I want to mirror them so the same image is on both screens. I want the larger display to shrink to the size of the smaller display, preferably adding black bars on the left and right to maintain the aspect ratio. Display settings doesn't help, because it only lets me select between the resolutions supported on both monitors. I looked into `xrandr`, but I can't find the right combination of flags. My current solution is

`xrandr --fb 3440x1440 --output DP-0 --mode 3440x1440 --pos 0x0 --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --same-as DP-0 --scale 0.895x0.666`

As I understand it,

- `--fb 3440x1440` sets the virtual display to `3440x1440`, which is my preferred size. I want this monitor to be displayed exactly as normal.
- `--output DP-0 --mode 3440x1440 --pos 0x0` sets the first monitor (DP-0) to resolution `3440x1440` at position 0,0, which should be exactly the virtual screen.
- `--output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --same-as DP-0 --scale 0.895x0.666` sets the TV to resolution `3840x2160`, aligns it on top of the first display, and scales it to `3440x1440`. This properly mirrors the screen, but it's stretched vertically.

How do I modify the above to maintain the aspect ratio? I was able to make `--set Border` work to add black bars, but I couldn't figure out how to do that and make the resolution on the larger monitor right. All my solutions end up with one of the monitors panning or worse, just clipping content. I tried using `0.666` for both the values for scale, but that causes my PC to go black for several minutes, the fans to spin at 100% the whole time, and when it returns, the monitors are arranged adjacently at their native resolutions, not mirrored. Or it hangs forever and I have to restart.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release? Scaling is easy with Wayland, and hard with X11

Comment: Whoops, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Comment: Double checked, and I have X11. Should I switch to wayland for ease of scaling?

Comment: You could just ***try*** Wayland first to see if it works. If it works, then make a decisuon